# Как при помощи PHPExcel загрузить содержимое таблицы в базу данных MySQL?

Tags: php, excel, плагин, phpexcel

Всем привет!

Скажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи PHPExcel сделать следующее: 
Имеется простая таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача - сделать при помощи этого инструмента так, чтобы данные из таблицы отправлялись в MySQL базу данных и значение каждой ячейки попадало в соответствующее поле в БД.

Нашел на англоязычном StackOverflow вот такое решение:

```
//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                NULL,
                                TRUE,
                                FALSE);
    //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
}
```

Но не разобрался с последним шагом. Как правильно написать запрос?

Заранее спасибо!

**UPDATE**

Структура таблицы такая: 
id first_name last_name

Более ничего, хочу просто понять логику как записываются данные.

Comment: `Как правильно написать запрос` Почитать мануалы по `Mysql`?

Comment: @u_mulder, подскажите, пожалуйста, на какой раздел обратить внимание?

Comment: Вероятно на раздел где рассказывается как добавлять записи в бд?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что здесь в БД записывается массив, а значит записать его так просто нельзя, нужно разбить на части. Или же использовать нестандартный запрос вида INSERT INTO ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечая на основной вопрос - загрузить данные в БД при помощи `PHPExcel` **нельзя**. **Никак**.

Для работы с базами данных в php существуют различные расширения - например PDO. Общий список расширений - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.database.php

Как выглядит запрос для вставки данных для СУБД Mysql (это наиболее часто используемая СУБД на вебе (хотя и тут можно поспорить)) можно прочитать, например, здесь http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

В общем виде запрос будет выглядеть как:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3);
```

Таким образом, для вставки данных в таблицу БД нужно написать правильный запрос и выполнить его, используя какое-либо SQL-расширение. Поскольку вы не написали структуру таблицы, то вам придется конструировать запрос самостоятельно, используя вышеуказанные ссылки.

**Обновление** с учетом структуры вашей таблицы запрос будет выглядеть так (TABLE_NAME - название вашей таблицы):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (0, 'Имя', 'Фамилия');
```

Значение `id` я проставил в `0` так как предполагаю что данное поле имеет свойство `Автоинкремент`. Иначе - можете установить свое значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ! Я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.